# Display instance variable with specific capitilization

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Ruby on Rails 3,
I have an instance variable that I want to display differently. 
Example: @type is "voip" The name of the directory being saved.

```
<%= @type %>
```

Or

```
<%= @type.titleize %>
```

These will display the @type as "voip in the first example and "Voip" in the second example.

I have done:

```
<%= link_to "VoIP" %>
```

Which will show the exact "VoIP" as above.
How can I do this with the instance variable @type? I want it to show "VoIP". Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the *cleanest* way that I can think of, but you could use [an acronym inflector](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections/acronym)...

The "mcdonald" example in the documentation would probably fit your need:

```
acronym 'McDonald'
underscore 'McDonald' #=> 'mcdonald'
camelize 'mcdonald' #=> 'McDonald'

acronym 'VoIP'
camelize 'voip' #=> 'VoIP'
```

Comment: I think this is a great way to do it. Atleast for me, I want that string as specified site wide. There must be a way to do it only on one page though. Thanks

Comment: Can somone inform me on how to enable all inflection rules? inflections.rb states they are not enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming @type holds the value "voip", you could use the following:

```
@type.gsub("voip", "VoIP")
```